# Is there a better way to check for opposite signs when comparing floats?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I have this piece of code which checks if two floats are opposite in their signs e.g. one is negative and other is positive vise versa. I feel there must be an easier way to do it than this.

```
// Checking if force applied is in opposite direction to movement of ball to apply greater force
    if (BallVelocityComponents.X > 0 && Value < 0)
    {
        FVector ForwardVector(Value * ForceApplied * 1500, 0.f, 0.f);
        StaticMesh->AddForce(ForwardVector);
    }
    else if (BallVelocityComponents.X < 0 && Value > 0)
    {
        FVector ForwardVector(Value * ForceApplied * 1500, 0.f, 0.f);
        StaticMesh->AddForce(ForwardVector);
    }
    else
    {
        FVector ForwardVector(Value * ForceApplied * 1000, 0.f, 0.f);
        StaticMesh->AddForce(ForwardVector);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::signbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit), this is what you are looking for.